# Generate an absolute url for my javascript file so it can be loaded by anyone

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have set up a server (node/express/mongodb) and in that server I have a javascript file (called e.g myscript.js).

So, I want to be able, to include this javascript file into any other website I host (like to include it in my head index.html into my other websites:  `<script src="path-to-my-server:8080/myscript.js"></script>` )

In the same way I can load this javascript file for example:

```
<script src="tutorialspoint.com/example.js"></script>
```

My server structure is like this: (if it's helpful)

```
-my_server
---node_modules
---server
------routes (api routes etc)
------models (models like users etc)
---config.js
---package.json
---server.js
---**myscript.js**
```

The main entry point for my server is server.js

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have Express set up, just create a route for your script in server.js:

```
const path = require("path");
app.get("/myscript.js", (req, res) => res.sendFile(path.resolve("./myscript.js")));
```

Or better yet, put your script in a subfolder (called "public" or similar) and use it as a static resource:

```
app.use("/", express.static("public"));
```

You don't have to worry about cross domain when a script is included with the `<script>` tag

Answer (score 0):

If you were wanting to do this using express you could just have a route return the javascript. I'd suggest looking at [cross domain policy rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Comment: So basically when you include a <scrip src="..."> to your <head> of index.html is like performing a HTTP GET request from that server ?